# Cast Object to known (but unknown) type

Tags: c#, dynamic, casting, runtime

Looking to cast an Object to a known type at runtime. I have a class (call it Item for ease) which is the base class for Box. Box has it's own properties as well as the ones from Item (obviously).

Basically I create an instance of Box using the `CreateInstance` method, this creates an Object of type object but the true type (as witnessed when doing 'typeof') is of type Box. I need to cast this Object back to Box without hard coding any `switch` / `if` etc. The code I have to test this is below and I'm running out of ideas.

```
//Base Class
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Reflection;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace Test11
{
    public class Item
    {
       public int property1 { get; set; }
       public int property2 { get; set; }
       public int property3 { get; set; }

    public Item()
    {
        property1 = 1;
        property2 = 2;
        property3 = 3;
    }
}

//Box Class - Inherits from Item
namespace Test11
{
    public class Box : Item
    {
        public int property4 { get; set; }

        public Box()
        {
            property4 = 4;
        }
    }
}

//Application Class
namespace Test11
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Item> BaseList = new List<Item>();
            object obj = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CreateInstance("Test11.Box");
            Type t = Type.GetType("Test11.Box");

            //The following line does not work, need to make it work :)
            //BaseList.Add(obj as t); 
            Console.WriteLine(t.ToString());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried many different ways now, the one featured above is one of many. Any ideas or help out there?

Comment: It's not possible. It will never be a strong typed instance of type `Box` unless you put a cast in your code. Casting to `Item` should be sufficient though.

Comment: Just cast it to `Item`. You'll be able to pass it to any method that accepts `Item`, or cast it explicitly later if you need to.

Comment: Could you please explain why is it not sufficient to simply cast `obj` to `Item`? Casting it to the exact type is not giving any additional information to `BaseList`, so it does not seem necessary.

Comment: what i don't understand is that if you can initialize an List<Item> why can't you cast it (obj as Item)? You are already hardcoding the item while initializing List, what kind of dynamic behavior are you looking for?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: I can't cast obj to Item as I would loose property4 from the class Box.

Comment: @cornerback84: The list actually contains various derived objects from Item. Many people think you can't do it but you can. The BaseList can contain any object aslong as it derives from Item and all their individual properties are still available.

Comment: Sorry guys fooled by Visual Studios different layouts. You all were right lol, when I tried casting to Item orginally it worked however i thought the property4 was lost. It actually is still there but Box cast to item you expand box to see the new properties were as if it is a true box you expand base to see the other properties.... oops.

Comment: In C++, this would be called "slicing". Since this is C# and stuff is (almost always) passed by reference, it's not a common problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `BaseList` is expecting `Item` objects. You *have* to cast:

```
if (obj is Item)
    BaseList.Add((Item)obj);
```

Or:

```
if (typeof(Item).IsAssignableFrom(t))
    BaseList.Add((Item)obj);
```

Comment: I can't really use these matey, both of them have hardcoded 'Item'. If I could do... BaseList.Add((typeof(obj)obj) to dynamically cast the obj object to its true form then its perfect but I cant :(.

Comment: But `BaseList` is expecting `Item` objects. Using the real type (as long as it inherits from `Item`) buys you nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Are you working with dynamically loaded assemblies? If you know for sure that it will be Box, could you declare Box as a partial class near Item and fill in the implementation details for it in your dynamic assembly?

Not sure if it'll work, I've not tried that particular problem.